# How to iterate week number, start/end date of weeks using moment

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datetime, isodate

How can I get all `week number`, `from/to date` of specific month?

The below code is what I construct to display `week number`, `from/to date` of specific month
and it returns infinite loop whenever I insert the function inside loop.

```
function getISOWeeksInMonth(month, year) {
    let weekStart = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);

    weekStart.setDate(weekStart.getDate() - (weekStart.getDay() || 7) + 1);

    let weekEnd = new Date(weekStart);
    weekEnd.setDate(weekEnd.getDate() + 6);

    let weekNum = moment(weekStart, "YYYY-MM-DD").week()

    let weeks = [];

    do {
        weeks.push({
            weekNum : weekNum++,
            start: new Date(weekStart),
            end: new Date(weekEnd)
        });

        weekStart.setDate(weekStart.getDate() + 7);
        weekEnd.setDate(weekEnd.getDate() + 7);
    } while (weekStart.getMonth() < month);

    return weeks;
}

_.forEach(moment.months(), function (month_name) {
    var month_number = moment().month(month_name).format("MM");

    getISOWeeksInMonth(month_number, 2022).forEach(week => console.log(
       'Week : ' + week.weekNum +
       '\nStart: ' + week.start.toDateString() + 
       '\nEnd  : ' + week.end.toDateString())
    );
})
```

Result should return the list the `week number`, `from/to date` 
Sample Url:
https://savvytime.com/week-number/philippines/2022

Here is the sample when I run the function outside loop:

```js
function getISOWeeksInMonth(month, year) {
    let weekStart = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);

    weekStart.setDate(weekStart.getDate() - (weekStart.getDay() || 7) + 1);

    let weekEnd = new Date(weekStart);
    weekEnd.setDate(weekEnd.getDate() + 6);


    let weekNum = moment(weekStart, "YYYY-MM-DD").week()

    let weeks = [];

    do {
        weeks.push({
            weekNum : weekNum++,
            start: new Date(weekStart),
            end: new Date(weekEnd)
        });

        weekStart.setDate(weekStart.getDate() + 7);
        weekEnd.setDate(weekEnd.getDate() + 7);
    } while (weekStart.getMonth() < month);

    return weeks;
}

getISOWeeksInMonth(1, 2022).forEach(week => console.log(
   'Week : ' + week.weekNum +
   '\nStart: ' + week.start.toDateString() + 
   '\nEnd  : ' + week.end.toDateString())
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getISOWeeksInMonth(month, year) {
    let weekStart = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);

    weekStart.setDate(weekStart.getDate() - (weekStart.getDay() || 7) + 1);

    let weekEnd = new Date(weekStart);
    weekEnd.setDate(weekEnd.getDate() + 6);

    let weeks = [];

    do {
        let weekNum = moment(weekStart, "YYYY-MM-DD").week()

        weeks.push({
            weekNum : weekNum,
            start: new Date(weekStart),
            end: new Date(weekEnd)
        });

        weekStart.setDate(weekStart.getDate() + 7);
        weekEnd.setDate(weekEnd.getDate() + 7);
    } while (weekStart.getMonth() < month && (weekStart.getMonth() || (month < 12) ));

    return weeks;
}

let _ = moment.months()
_.forEach(function (month_name) {
    var month_number = moment().month(month_name).format("MM");

    getISOWeeksInMonth(month_number, 2022).forEach(week => console.log(
       'Week : ' + week.weekNum +
       '\nStart: ' + week.start.toDateString() + 
       '\nEnd  : ' + week.end.toDateString())
    );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

When you calculate the weeks in December (month 12), you're starting with the last week in the prior month (November, i.e. 11), and in your `do {...} while` loop, you're adding 7 days to `weekStart`. So far so good, but your `while (weekStart.getMonth() < month)` is checking the 0-11 value of `weekStart.getMonth()`, and when it rolls forward from 11, instead of going to 12 it goes to 0. So it is always less than 12 (December!)!

You can fix this by adjusting your `while` to:

```
while (weekStart.getMonth() < month && (weekStart.getMonth() || (month < 12) ))
```

Comment: I would like to ask why there's a duplicate week? such as week # 27, 45 49 etc.

Comment: @StoledInk That's because any week that overlaps a month boundary, e.g. Jan 31 2022 - Feb 6 2022, can be considered to be both the last week in January, as well as the first week in February. So when we calculate all the weeks in January, we will get the last one as 1/31/2022-2/6/2022, and when we calculate all the weeks in February we will get the first one as 1/31/2022-2/6/2022 (the same). If you want to weed out those duplicates you'll have to check if `start.getMonth() != end.getMonth()`, then it's a duplicate from the previous/next month.

Comment: Another question, I set the year to 2023 and the starting week number is `53` instead of `1`

Comment: @StoledInk Your calculation of `weekNum` was wrong. I have fixed it and updated my answer.